# How to resize an object after a jQuery toggle?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate, toggle

Thanks ahead of time.  I am new to jQuery, and this is my first question on Stack:

I have a toggle function, which animates two divs, #B and #C, to the left and right:

```
$("#toggleNav").toggle(
  function() {
    $("#B").stop(true).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 130)
    $("#C").stop(true).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 130)
  }, function() {
    $("#B").stop(true).animate({
      left: 80
    }, 130)
    $("#C").stop(true).animate({
      left: 300
    }, 130)
});
```

The width of div #C is the remaining width of the window.  So as the window resizes, div #C gets bigger and smaller.

Within div #C, I have a [Wijmo line chart](http://wijmo.com/widgets/wijmo-complete/charts-line-chart/) widget that is redrawn to fit div #C whenever the window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#wijlinechart").wijlinechart("redraw");
});
```

I want the chart to be redrawn to the resulting size of div #C after the toggle has been completed.  I tried this, among many other things:

```
$("#toggleNav").toggle(
  function() {
    $("#B").stop(true).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 130)
    $("#C").stop(true).animate({
      left: 0
    }, 130)
    $("#wijlinechart").wijlinechart("redraw");
  }, function() {
    $("#B").stop(true).animate({
      left: 80
    }, 130)
    $("#C").stop(true).animate({
      left: 300
    }, 130)
    $("#wijlinechart").wijlinechart("redraw");
});
```

At this point, when div #C is resized, the line chart is redrawn, but it is redrawn to the size of div #C prior to the resize.  So as div #C gets smaller, the chart gets bigger, and as div #C gets bigger, the chart gets smaller.

How can I delay the redraw until after the toggle has completed?  Or call a redraw function upon completion of the toggle?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)'s callback (complete) parameter.

```
$("#C").stop(true).animate({
    left: 0
}, 130, function(){//pass a function callback to be executed when animation ends
    $("#wijlinechart").wijlinechart("redraw");
});
```

Move both of the `redraw` calls to `.animate` callbacks and it will work as expected.